# Package bash-completion missing from Yum in CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, dnf

I am trying to get tab-completion working in Yum in CentOS 6 (so I can do something like `yum install firefo<TAB>` and get back `firefox`), and I have found many tutorials which say to simply do `yum install bash-completion`, but when I do this, I get this back:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.anl.gov
 * extras: yum.singlehop.com
 * updates: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
Setting up Install Process
No package bash-completion available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Is there some repository I should add?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CentOS needs to have EPEL Yum repository enabled in order to install bash-completion package.

See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL for details.

Answer (score 8):

There is only one command you have to get bash-completion:

```
yum install epel-release.noarch bash-completion.noarch
```

Comment: Concisely perfect!

Answer (score 4):

1. Download the `bash-completion` RPM

   `wget http://www.caliban.org/files/redhat/RPMS/noarch/bash-completion-20060301-1.noarch.rpm`
2. Install the RPM

   `rpm -ivh bash-completion-20060301-1.noarch.rpm`
3. Execute the command

   `. /etc/bash_completion`
4. Now you can try the autocompletion

   `yum ins — [TAB][TAB]`

Edit: for Centos 6, you can grab [this RPM](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/bash-completion/bash-completion-20060301-1.el6.rf.noarch.rpm)

Comment: Installing unsigned packages from untrusted source is huge security risk.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have EPEL installed then first run:

```
yum install epel-release
```

Then run the following command:

```
yum install bash-completion --enablerepo=epel
```

After installation you have to logout/login in order for it to start working. To start using it in the current session, source it with the `.` command:

```
. /etc/bash_completion
```