# Cannot install PHP packages in CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, php

In CentOS 6.3 (**Edit**: updated to 6.4) I can't install any PHP (MySQL, and many other) packages.

For example output of `yum install php-devel` is:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.vit.com.tr
 * extras: mirrors.prometeus.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirrors.prometeus.net
Setting up Install Process
No package php-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

output of `ls /etc/yum.repos.d`:

```
CentOS-Base.repo  CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  CentOS-Media.repo  CentOS-Vault.repo  mirrors-rpmforge  rpmforge.repo
```

`grep -E "name|enabled" /etc/yum.repos.d/*`:

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo:name=CentOS-6 - Debuginfo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo:name=CentOS-$releasever - Media
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:name=CentOS-6.0 - Base
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:name=CentOS-6.0 - Updates
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:name=CentOS-6.0 - Extras
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:name=CentOS-6.0 - Contrib
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:name=CentOS-6.0 - CentOSPlus
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:name=CentOS-6.1 - Base
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:name=CentOS-6.1 - Updates
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:name=CentOS-6.1 - Extras
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:name=CentOS-6.1 - Contrib
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:name=CentOS-6.1 - CentOSPlus
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:name=CentOS-6.2 - Base
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:name=CentOS-6.2 - Updates
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:name=CentOS-6.2 - Extras
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:name=CentOS-6.2 - Contrib
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:name=CentOS-6.2 - CentOSPlus
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:enabled=0
/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo:name = Red Hat Enterprise $releasever - RPMforge.net - dag
/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo:enabled = 1
```

`yum repolist`:

```
repo id                                           repo name                                                                          status
base                                              CentOS-6 - Base                                                                      6,296+85
extras                                            CentOS-6 - Extras                                                                          13
rpmforge                                          Red Hat Enterprise 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                                          11,131+144
updates                                           CentOS-6 - Updates                                                                     890+34
```

`yum list available 'php-*'`:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.vit.com.tr
 * extras: mirrors.prometeus.net
 * rpmforge: www.mirrorservice.org
 * updates: mirrors.prometeus.net
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

This happens for all PHP packages. When I type `php-` and press tab key there is no auto completion. Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have the repos enabled? grep -E "name|enabled" /etc/yum.repos.d/*

Comment: @AlexandreAlves I added result of the command to post. I seems needed repos are enabled(?)

Comment: See the 1st part of my answer, you need to install a package to get the completion working. Also after installing the package you need to do a `. /etc/bash_completion` in a shell to get it to work. I think a logging out/in would also do it.

Comment: php-devel is in base, so there's likely something else going on here.

Comment: @hpn - not sure if you saw my suggestion on my answer, can you please run this command to see if it works? `yum --enablerepo=\* search php-devel`.

Comment: @hpn - where are we at with this? I'd like to help you further but haven't heard back.

Answer (score 20):

Some software like cpanel disable php in `/etc/yum.conf`

```
exclude= php*  mysql*
```

If your /etc/yum.conf file contains above line simple remove php* from that line
After that you can install php :)

Comment: this is what is was for me (whm/cpanel) but it wasnt that simple, as my system was running 5.4 and when i took out php* from the exclude it yum offered me php 5.3 from the repo which would have broken my system with dependency problems and whm/cpanel conflicts. so ive been advised to avoid it, and im going to compile my module against php-devel on a virtual machine instead.

Answer (score 6):

From the question and from the output, it seems that you only have the  RPMForge repo enabled and nothing more.

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo:name = Red Hat Enterprise $releasever - RPMforge.net - dag
/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo:enabled = 1
```

So run:

```
# yum repolist disabled
repo id                                                            repo name
fedora/19/x86_64                                                   Fedora 19 - x86_64
fedora-debuginfo/19/x86_64                                         Fedora 19 - x86_64 - Debug
fedora-source/19/x86_64                                            Fedora 19 - Source
updates-debuginfo/19/x86_64                                        Fedora 19 - x86_64 - Updates - Debug
updates-testing/19/x86_64                                          Fedora 19 - x86_64 - Test Updates
updates-testing-debuginfo/19/x86_64                                Fedora 19 - x86_64 - Test Updates Debug
updates-testing-source/19/x86_64                                   Fedora 19 - Test Updates Source
```

Now to enable the desired repo:
`yum-config-manager --enable fedora-source`

In your case it should be `base`

Answer (score 3):

#### bash completition

I do not believe that `yum` will perform auto completion when you hit the <kbd>tab</kbd> key by default. I found this U&L Q&A titled: [Package bash-completion missing from Yum in CentOS 6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21135/package-bash-completion-missing-from-yum-in-centos-6), and it looks as if you need to install the package `bash-completion`.

```
$ sudo yum install bash-completion
```

#### repolist

I would make use of some of yum's other features to determine what's going on. For starters you can see what repos yum knows about:

```
$ yum repolist
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
repo id                    repo name                                      status
Dropbox                    Dropbox Repository                                  4
adobe-linux-i386           Adobe Systems Incorporated                         17
adobe-linux-x86_64         Adobe Systems Incorporated                          2
fedora                     Fedora 14 - x86_64                             22,161
google-chrome              google-chrome                                       3
google-earth               google-earth                                        1
google-talkplugin          google-talkplugin                                   1
lamolabs                   LamoLabs Repo                                      58
lamolabs-noarch            LamoLabs Repo                                       2
nautilus-flickr-uploader   Nautilus Flickr Uploader for Fedora 14              3
rpmfusion-free             RPM Fusion for Fedora 14 - Free                   411
rpmfusion-free-updates     RPM Fusion for Fedora 14 - Free - Updates         642
rpmfusion-nonfree          RPM Fusion for Fedora 14 - Nonfree                181
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates  RPM Fusion for Fedora 14 - Nonfree - Updates      282
scootersoftware            Scooter Software                                    1
updates                    Fedora 14 - x86_64 - Updates                    9,982
wuala                      cdn.wuala.com                                       8
```

#### list available

You can also use this command to see what's available in the repos that you have access to:

```
$ yum list available 'php-*'
php-mapi.x86_64                                     7.0.3-1.fc14         updates
php-mapserver.x86_64                                5.6.7-1.fc14         updates
php-markdown.noarch                                 1.0.1n-1.fc14        fedora·
php-mbstring.x86_64                                 5.3.8-3.fc14         updates
php-mcrypt.x86_64                                   5.3.8-3.fc14         updates
php-mssql.x86_64                                    5.3.8-3.fc14         updates
php-mysql.x86_64                                    5.3.8-3.fc14         updates
php-nusoap.noarch                                   0.9.5-1.fc14         fedora·
php-oauth.noarch                                    1.0-0.7.svn592.fc12  fedora·
php-odbc.x86_64                                     5.3.8-3.fc14         updates
...
```

#### search

You can just search the repositories too using this command:

```
$ yum search 'php-devel'
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
============================== Matched: php-devel ==============================
php-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
php-devel.i686 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
ice-php-devel.i686 : Tools for developing Ice applications in PHP
ice-php-devel.x86_64 : Tools for developing Ice applications in PHP
```

#### repoquery

You can use this tool if you have access to a repo to find out which repo is providing a given package:

```
$ repoquery php-devel
php-devel-0:5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64

$ repoquery -i php-devel

Name        : php-devel
Version     : 5.3.3
Release     : 22.el6
Architecture: x86_64
Size        : 3188116
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
Group       : Development/Libraries
URL         : http://www.php.net/
Repository  : base
Summary     : Files needed for building PHP extensions
Source      : php-5.3.3-22.el6.src.rpm
Description :
The php-devel package contains the files needed for building PHP
extensions. If you need to compile your own PHP extensions, you will
need to install this package.
```

From the above we can see that the package `php-devel` is coming out of the `base` repository.

#### fastestmirror

Sometimes this plugin can be causing your issue. You can remove it's cache of which mirrors to use so that it can be regenerated.

```
$ locate timedhosts.txt
/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/timedhosts.txt

$ sudo rm /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/timedhosts.txt
```

Then run your yum install php-devel command again.

#### verbose

Most of the commands mentioned above can take the switch `--verbose` or `-v`. For example you can run the `yum list available <pkg>` command to gain some insight into what `yum` is actually doing behind the scenes:

```
$ yum --verbose list available php-devel
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Loading "priorities" plugin
Loading "refresh-packagekit" plugin
Config time: 0.020
Yum Version: 3.2.29
Setting up Package Sacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.thelinuxfix.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: yum.singlehop.com
 * updates: ftpmirror.your.org
 --> python-netaddr-0.7.5-4.el6.noarch from base excluded (priority)
 --> python-tw-forms-0.9.9-1.el6.noarch from base excluded (priority)

 ...
 ...

 --> wxGTK-devel-2.8.12-1.el6.centos.x86_64 from extras excluded (priority)
73 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
pkgsack time: 6.174
rpmdb time: 0.000
Available Packages
php-devel.x86_64                        5.3.3-22.el6                        base
```

#### base repos disabled?

In looking at your output from the commands you ran it looks like your base repos are disabled (`/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:enabled=0`), they need to be enabled.

You can either edit those files and change the lines from 0 to 1 or run this commands:

```
$ yum-config-manager --enable base
$ yum-config-manager --enable updates
```

#### enable all repos

You could also try to just enable all your repos with this command:

```
$ yum --enablerepo=\* search php-devel
```

Comment: I edited my question with result of these commands.

Comment: @hpn - see updates. Have you tried doing a `yum clean all` too?

Comment: Thanks, but removing timedhosts.txt and running `yum clean all` didn't work.

Comment: When I run `yumdownloader --urls php-devel` I get this value: http://mirror.thelinuxfix.com/CentOS/6.4/os/x86_64//Packages/php-devel-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64.rpm. Realize that this is different depending which mirror I'm hitting, but can you confirm that you can ping this server? I'm wondering if you're having a networking problem.

Comment: Yes, I can ping thelinuxfix.com

Comment: @hpn - hopefully you aren't getting too frustrated with my requests, can you please try this command? `$ yum --verbose list available php-devel`.

Comment: @hpn - when you get a chance can you also check the output of this command? `yum repolist -v`.

Comment: @hpn - your base repos are disabled (/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:enabled=0
), they need to be enabled. You can either edit those files and change the lines from 0 to 1 or `yum-config-manager --enable base` and `yum-config-manager --enable updates`.

Comment: Thanks, but running these commands also didn't work.

Comment: @hpn - what happens when you enable all the repositories: `yum --enablerepo=\* search php-devel`? I'm still convinced that your repositories aren't enabled.

Comment: It could also be that the repo files have `exclude=php*` or something like that in them.